# Get values from multiple inputs without re-writing the same code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var attributeVariables = ['thing1', 'thing2'];

$.each(attributeVariables, function(index, val) {
   attributeVariables[index] = $('input[name='+attributeVariables[index]+']:checked').val();
});

console.log(thing1+" , "+thing2)
```

In the console, this yields `undefined , undefined`

However, if I run these, I get the proper value for `thing1` and `thing2`

```
thing1 = $('input[name=thing1]:checked').val(); 
thing2 = $('input[name=thing2]:checked').val();
```

I have a bunch of other variables that a structured the same to get their value. I'm trying to avoid writing the lines above 50 times. I know there's a better way and I thought I had it with my first statement. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

UPDATE:
All I'm trying to do is update these already existing variables (`thing1`, `thing2`) based on the logic in my `each`...not store everything in an array.

UPDATE 2:
Restated another way...I'm not married to doing this any specific way. Here's what I need: I have about 30 radio selectors, each tied to a different variable. Rather than write this out 30 times for 30 different variables (`thing2 = $('input[name=thing2]:checked').val();`), I figured there was a shortcut. I'd make a list of all the variables I want updated (based on the radio states) and run a single `each`

Comment: try console.log(attributeVariables) instead of console.log(thing1 + " , " + thing2), since that's what you are assigning the value to in the first example. You never create variables called thing1 or thing2, so it only makes since that they aren't defined.

Comment: Try `console.log(attributeVariables.join()`) instead

Comment: @ZackaryMurphy I thought that I was defining them in my `each` just like I define them in my standalone statements. That is, these variables are equal to the current state of the input with this name. No?

Comment: @ZackaryMurphy And I'm just trying to update these variables, which have already been set.

Comment: @jonmrich no you are replacing the values in the original array inside the `each`

Comment: @charlietfl that's not what I want. What I want it to update each of the variables (listed by name in the `attributesVariables`) based on what's in my `each`

Comment: No you don't! First those variables don't exist and doing individual variables for 50+ items is crazy. Use an object instead

Comment: @charlietfl They do exist. I defined them once initially (not shown here). But when the user changes the value, I want to get the value of all of these variables (on button click).

Comment: What is the use case? Can get all this using much simpler approaches depending on what you are trying to do with it all

Comment: @charlietfl That's what I'm thinking, but not sure how. I have about 30 radio selectors, each tied to a different variable. Rather than write this out 30 times for 30 different variables (`thing2 = $('input[name=thing2]:checked').val();`), I figured there was a shortcut. I'd make a list of all the variables I want updated (based on the radio states) and run a single `each`

Comment: If this is to submit a form can do it in one line. If it is for storing data from a form can be done simply also using jQuery form methods

Comment: @charlietfl It's not currently a form, but I guess I could easily make it one.

Comment: Still haven't identified what use case is. This is definitely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @jonmrich there is no purpose in `console.log(thing1+" , "+thing2) ` when **in the above question** there is no definition for `thing1` and `thing2`. Please edit with only the relevant code to your question

Comment: @charlietfl The use case. 30 different inputs (radio: true/false). On button click, get all of the current values of all 30 radios and update 30 variables. The variable names are the same as the input names (which I thought would make it simpler).

Comment: The problem about the `<input type="radio">` is that the bound radio buttons need to have the same `name` attribute. Maybe then you can use `id` instead of `name`...

Comment: @jonmrich that is what you are trying to do with the code...not what you are doing with the results - as in use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at the comments you are not `console.log()`-ing the right thing. Otherwise your code is almost fine. I think you can use directly `val` in the `each` instead `attributeVariables[index]`.

Then you can perform an conditional check because `val()` of not checked checkboxes returns `undefined`

```js
var attributeVariables = ['thing1', 'thing2'];

$.each(attributeVariables, function(index, val) {
  attributeVariables[index] = {
    name: val,
    checked: $('input[name=' + val + ']:checked').val() ? true : false
  };
});

console.log(attributeVariables);
console.log('--------------------------------');
console.log('Radio Buttons Test Results');

var radios = ['thing3', 'thing4', 'thing5', 'thing6'];
$.each(radios, function(idx, name) {
  var radioValues = [];
  $.each($('input[name=' + name + ']'), function(i, radio) {
    radioValues.push({index: i, checked: radio.checked});
  });
  
  radios[idx] = {
    name: name,
    radioValues: radioValues
  };
});

console.log(radios);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="thing1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="thing2">
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="thing3">
<input type="radio" name="thing3" checked>
<input type="radio" name="thing3">
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="thing4">
<input type="radio" name="thing4">
<input type="radio" name="thing4" checked>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="thing5" checked>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="thing6">
```

Comment: These are always coming out as `true` for me regardless of the actual input value. I'm using `radio` type if that changes things.

Comment: Yes, radio is another story, as I commented under your question. But we will work around that

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that comment

Comment: @jonmrich see the updated code. What I've mean is that if you want radio buttons to work together you need to put them the same `name`(_see my code_). Now in the updated code we are taking care for the froups of radio buttons when we do another loop inside the `$.each`. In the `radioValues` you will see the index of this radio and if it is checked

Answer (score 1):

try this. it might works...

```
var inputsObject = {};
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    inputsObject[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val()
})
console.log(inputsObject)
```

in inputsObject u will have pairs (name => value) if they exist.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to update variables with the value of each input given that the input name is the same as the variable name?

Comment: but look, u have an object inputsObject, inside u have
`{
thing1: on,
thing2: off
}`
and then u have easy access from inputsObject to every key of object, which name is equals to input name. O

Comment: I know, but I've tried a few things and can't quite get it right. I know I need an `each` but struggling after that.

Comment: with this variant u have access to all of your checked inputs via `inputsObject.inputName`